# TypeError: this.slider.blur is not a function

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to test a method which calls `slider.blur()`. When I run my spec I get `TypeError: this.slider.blur is not a function`.

What do I need to do to allow this `@ViewChild('slider') slider: MatSlider;` to be used in my test?

**Component**

```
import { MatSlider } from '@angular/material/slider';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('slider') slider: MatSlider;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  updateAndToggle(newVal) {
    if (!this.widgetDisabled) {
      this.toggleForm.controls.toggleVal.setValue(newVal);
      this.toggle();
    }
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.slider.blur();
  }
}
```

**Spec**

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(
    waitForAsync(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientModule, LoggerTestingModule],
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      }).compileComponents();
    })
  );

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should do something', () => {
    component.doSomething(); 
    // TypeError: this.slider.blur is not a function
  });
});
```

Comment: Try adding `MatSliderModule` to imports of `configureTestingModule`

Comment: `@ViewChild('slider') slider: MatSlider;` is an ambitious declaration, because `@ViewChild` can always return `undefined`